# How to call a method every X seconds using JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have jsp page that displays the entries of a database. I also have a method that scans this database and which deletes the entries that have "expired". This is based on manipulating dates. I want this method to be called every X seconds in the jsp page using JSTL, so that the entries that have expired are no longer displayed. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Once your JSP is loaded on browser, you can not invoke java code. So there is no point of having any logic to call method every x seconds through jsp.

However, You can -

1. refresh your jsp every x seconds
2. make an ajax call to fetch latest data from DB and display it using
   javascript/jquery